# Performance of importing classes with and without the use keyword

Tags: php

**Consider the following:**

I have a class that does some mild reporting,

**example 1**

```
<?php
    namespace App\Log;

    class Reporting
    {   
        private $config;

        function __construct($config)
        {
            $this->config = $config;
        }

        public function ReportSomething($action)
        {
            // blah blah, sends data to a server
        }
    }
?>
```

Then I also class where I want to use the Reporting class multiple times:

**example 2**

```
<?php
    namespace App\Controller

    use App\Log\Reporting;

    class DoStuff
    {

        public function getUser() 
        {
            // blah blah, business logic
            $reporting = new Reporting($config);
            $reporting->ReportSomething('going to db');
            $reporting->ReportSomething('got data');

            $reporting2 = new Reporting($newConfig);
            $reporting2->ReportSomething('preparing to send');
            $reporting2->ReportSomething('sent');
        }

        public function getPosts() 
        {
            // blah blah, business logic
            $reporting = new Reporting($config);
            $reporting->ReportSomething('going to db');
            $reporting->ReportSomething('got data');

            $reporting2 = new Reporting($newConfig);
            $reporting2->ReportSomething('preparing to send');
            $reporting2->ReportSomething('sent');
        }

        /* you get the point */
    }
?>
```

**My question is:** performance wise, what would be the impact if I were to use this type of style instead:

**example 3**

```
<?php
    namespace App\Controller

    class DoStuff
    {

        public function getUser() 
        {
            // blah blah, business logic
            $reporting = new \App\Log\Reporting($config);
            $reporting->ReportSomething('going to db');
            $reporting->ReportSomething('got data');

            $reporting2 = new \App\Log\Reporting($newConfig);
            $reporting2->ReportSomething('preparing to send');
            $reporting2->ReportSomething('sent');
        }

        public function getPosts() 
        {
            // blah blah, business logic
            $reporting = new \App\Log\Reporting($config);
            $reporting->ReportSomething('going to db');
            $reporting->ReportSomething('got data');

            $reporting2 = new \App\Log\Reporting($newConfig);
            $reporting2->ReportSomething('preparing to send');
            $reporting2->ReportSomething('sent');
        }

        /* you get the point */
    }
?>
```

Where, as you can see, example 3 no longer uses the `use` keyword to import, but rather does `new \App\Log\Reporting` each time it wants to obtain a new instance of the `Reporting` class.

Are there any downsides to either use cases? Is one better (based on some data or information) than another, and why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`use` and `namespace` don't actually access the class, they simply store the namespace or class as a string so they will run at relatively similar speeds. Given that I would go for example 2 since it encourages the organizational structure thats offered by using those keywords.

Comment: So essentially what you're saying is there are no performance differences between the two?

Comment: Yes, namespaces and uses only exist as a hashtable in the scope they are defined. When you call a function class or variable it will look for an existing reference in that table. Hash lookups are typically O(1) which means you should recieve almost no performance hit, but you may find the 3rd example to run ever so slightly faster due to this. That being said, the organization structure afforded by example 2 is far more valuable than any speed increase you would recieve from the direct references in example 3.

Comment: That's interesting. Even though I'm using `new \App\Log\Reporting($config)` twice over the `Reporting::config($config)` ?

Comment: Logically, I thought that the `use` keyword would perform the lookup once, then it can be used anywhere in the class without another lookup

Comment: You would have to use this method millions of times to see even a small effect on your runtime. The lookup is performed every time that you reference the class regardless of if it's been use'd or not. Heres a small script to illustrate, try running it on yours as well. EDIT: code https://paste.ofcode.org/3weWTWtwXpdPY4xGcWAFtu

Comment: Thanks, I think you've answered all I got. Upvoted at accepted.

Comment: happy to help! I hope you got everything you needed